# Prove that $f$ is a diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $$E = \left\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1 \right\}$$ for some $a,b,c > 0$. Prove that the function $$f:E \to S^2, \quad (x,y,z) \mapsto \left( \frac{x}{a}, \frac{y}{b}, \frac{z}{c} \right)$$
is a diffeomorphism.

Ok, so I need to prove that $f$ is smooth with smooth inverse. By definition, smooth means that for any $p\in E$ there exist smooth charts $(U, \varphi)$ containing $p$ and $(V, \psi)$ containing $f(p)$ such that $f(U) \subset V$ and the composite map $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ from $\varphi(U)$ to $\psi(V)$ is smooth in the ordinary sense of calculus.

I guess what I need to do is equip $E$ and $S^2$ with smooth structures such that $f$ is smooth iff $f$ is smooth in the ordinary sense of calculus. Will this work if I choose the standard smooth structure for $S^2$ and the smooth structure induced by $\{ (E, id_{E}) \}$ for $E$?

Maybe I'm making this way too complicated. Please help me.

Comment: One can also describe $f$ and $f^{-1}$ as compositions of smooth functions; this is helpful inasmuch as it avoids picking charts and computing coordinate representations.

Comment: Uh , isn't all the components linear…? Wouldn't the charts just be identity?

Comment: @Travis can you elaborate? compositions of what smooth functions?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas As written, $f$ is the restriction of a linear function $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. And we can precompose this map with the inclusion $E \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. These are both smooth, so all that we need to conclude that $f$ is smooth is the standard fact that if $g: M \to N$ is a smooth map such that the image $g(M)$ of $g$ is in contained in a submanifold $S \subset N$, then $g$ is also smooth regarded as a map $M \to S$.

Comment: @Travis thanks, makes sense. Can you elaborate why the inclusion map $E \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is smooth?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it was useful. Inclusion maps of (embedded) submanifolds are always smooth, because embeddedness guarantees the existence of *slice charts* of the big manifold at any point of the embdedded submanifold. Here, it means that for any $p \in E$ there is a chart $(U, \phi)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\phi(E \cap U) = (\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0\}) \cap \phi(U)$. In any such chart, the coordinate representation of the inclusion map $\iota$ is $\hat{\iota}(x, y) = (x, y, 0)$, which of course is smooth.